# Extending TInterpolationType in Delphi's TAnimation

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am working on a Delphi application using the FMX framework and I am trying to extend the `TAnimation` class to add my own custom interpolation algorithms. The `TAnimation` class uses an enumerated type `TInterpolationType` to allow users to select the interpolation algorithm they wish to use:

```
TInterpolationType = (Linear, Quadratic, Cubic, Quartic, Quintic, Sinusoidal, Exponential, Circular, Elastic, Back, Bounce);
```

This can be set via the Interpolation property:

```
property Interpolation: TInterpolationType read FInterpolation write FInterpolation default TInterpolationType.Linear;
```

There are many other interpolation algorithms available (e.g., Accelerate interpolator, Decelerate interpolator, Anticipate interpolator, Hesitate interpolator, Spring interpolator, etc.), and I would like to update the `TAnimation` class so that I can define and use my own interpolation algorithm.

By what can I replace (or extend) the `Interpolation` property so that I can also include my own custom interpolation algorithms?

Right now I think to add "Custom" in `TInterpolationType = (Linear, Quadratic, Cubic, Quartic, Quintic, Sinusoidal, Exponential, Circular, Elastic, Back, Bounce, CUSTOM);` and add an event OnCustomInterpolation but Would like to know if their is not a more elegant solution?

Comment: The way how TAnimation is currently codded I'm afraid you won't have an easy time extending it. Why? If you look at its source code you will see that the only place where `FInterpolation` field is used is in [TAnimation.GetNormalizedTime](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Ani.TAnimation.GetNormalizedTime) protected method. The said method has just one case statement which then calls appropriate Interpolation methods based on InterpolationType. So no easy way of changing this without rewriting the existing `TAnimation` class. ...

Comment: ... On the other hand since `GetNormalizedTime` is getter method for [NormalizedTime](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.Ani.TAnimation.NormalizedTime) you might be able to redeclare same named property that would use your custom getter method.

Comment: Any way if you do decide to go and rewrite `TAnimation` I'm guessing that just adding ability for us to specify custom Interpolation method would be best solution since then you can write nay interpolation method you need. But it seems that original authors of `TAnimation` class never expected anyone to try and extend this class by adding other Interpolations. I long for days of Delphi 6 when extending any of the code that shipped with Delphi was simple as making class derivation. Nowadays you are often forced into using RTTL hacks to do what could be done by simple class derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to add "Custom" in TInterpolationType = (Linear, Quadratic, Cubic, Quartic, Quintic, Sinusoidal, Exponential, Circular, Elastic, Back, Bounce, CUSTOM); and add an event OnCustomInterpolation

The code is visible at https://github.com/MagicFoundation/Alcinoe

**Interpolated Animation**

The TALAnimation component is a refined iteration of Delphi's foundational TAnimation object, meticulously tailored for mobile platforms. By forgoing the traditional Timer mechanism and instead adopting platform-specific technologies, this component offers a vastly improved animation experience for mobile users. On Android, animations are seamlessly integrated with the Choreographer, ensuring they sync perfectly with the device's refresh rate. Meanwhile, on iOS, the precision of DisplayLink is harnessed, leading to optimized and fluid animation rendering. Beyond these foundational changes, one of the most notable enhancements is the capability to support custom interpolation algorithms. This offers developers the flexibility to design unique and intricate animation patterns, moving beyond the traditional ease-in or ease-out sequences.

[image]
[image]

**SpringForce Animation**

Inspired by Android's SpringForce, the TALSpringForceAnimation Component brings the intrigue of physics-based animations to the Delphi platform. This component captures the real-world dynamism of objects influenced by spring mechanics. The resulting animations are ones that stretch, bounce, and settle, mirroring real-world behaviors and offering a tangible sense of realism to users. Developers have the added advantage of being able to adjust various physical properties of the spring, such as its stiffness and damping ratio. This ensures that a broad spectrum of animation behaviors can be realized, catering to the specific nuances of different applications.

[image]